# Assign MAX(id) to Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbuilder

I want to make some inserts into a table,  using some data from powerbuilder.  I am a little lost when it comes to using SQL sequences to increment the last known ID.

I know how to find the max ID, but how can I use a sequence to make sure that every new INSERT increments the ID by 1?

So far all I have is how to find my max id:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM table_name;
```

**EDIT**
I am using Oracle for my database

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In oracle, to get the next value in the sequence, you use .nextval.

Example :

```
select my_sequence.nextval from dual;
```

When you are importing data and let's say ids till 10000 have been used up already, you could alter your sequence to increment by that number. Since this is DDL, you might have to use Dynamic SQL.

```
declare
  l_current_max_value number;
  l_dummy number
begin
  select max(id)
    into l_current_max_value 
    from my_table;

  for i in 1..l_current_max_value loop
    l_dummy := l_current_max_value.nextval; --bouncing the sequence, 
                                            --another option is to recreate it.
  end loop; 

end;
/
```

NOTE: THis is asuming your current sequence isn't used at all. If you are importing data into an existing table with data, it will be more work along the same lines and you need to think about common Ids in both tables.

> EDIT : "how do I assign the current_max_number to the my_sequence"

Once all the importing is done, you can get the ids using .nextval. Eg.

```
create or replace procedure new_product(
  i_sku in number,
  i_name in varchar2(100)
)
as
begin
  insert into new_product (id, sku, name)
  values (product_seq.nextval, i_sku, i_name);

  commit;
end;
/
```

or you can get it into a variable for any further processing..

```
declare
 l_next_id number;
begin
 select my_sequence.nextval
   into l_next_id
   from dual;
 --further processing
end;
/
```

Comment: I'd say `start with`, not `increment by` )

Comment: how do I assign the current_max_number to the `my_sequence`

Comment: @beherenow : I think, when importing data, both of them yield the same result. If the sequence is already present, I would rather increment it. Any reason you prefer to recreate the sequence?

Comment: @RajeshChamarthi say you need ids 101, 102, 103 etc, starting from 100. if you set `increment by 100` (max(id)), then you will get 100, 200, 300 etc on each `.nextval`

Comment: @steve rolling your sequence up to a desired number `begin cv := seq.currval; for i in cv .. current_max_number loop tmp := seq.nextval; end loop; end;` will prevent you from recreating it

Comment: @beherenow: Thanks! Never had to use that option in an alter and turns out I understood it wrong. Also, another reason to test code before posting :). edited my code now.

Answer (score 3):

If IDs' values of a table you are inserting data into come from an already existed in your schema sequence then you are welcome to keep using that sequence to insert new records.

If you want to create a new sequence that would generate numbers starting from the maximum value of `ID` column of your table then you can do the following

Create sequence:

```
create sequence Seq_Name;
```

Change the value sequence would start with

```
declare
  l_max_ID number;
  l_Temp_val number;
begin
  select max(ID) into l_max_ID
    from your_table;

  execute immediate 'alter sequence Seq_Name increment by ' || To_Char(l_Max_ID);

  select Seq_Name.currval into l_temp_val
    from dual;

  execute immediate 'alter sequence Seq_Name increment by ' || To_Char(1);
end;
```

And use any of listed below approaches to get next value of the sequence.

```
Insert into your_table(id, [other_columns])
  values(Seq_name.nextval, [other_values]);
```

OR

```
create or replace trigger Tr_Name before insert on Your_Table_name
for each row
begin
  -- if you are using oracle prior to 11g then 
  select Seq_name.nextval into :new.id -- or any other column
    from dual;
  --     OR
  -- if your Oracle version is 11g onward you can simply assign 
  -- sequence's value to a new ID
  :new.id := Seq_Name.nextval;

end;
```

Comment: I get a syntax error right off the bat, that points to `create sequence max_id_seq;`

Comment: What error did you get? What client you are using to execute that statement? There have to be no error.

Comment: I am using powerbuilder classic 12.0.  I am writing it inside my procedure.

Comment: The cases of the variable above in the `declare` section and in the `execute immediate` statement don't match -- need to be `l_max_ID` in both places.

Comment: @TheLifeOfSteve If you get an error on `create sequence max_id_seq;`, best is to do `drop sequence max_id_seq;` and re-create it.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I found that if I ran that `declare...begin...end` statement above, I'd get the right answer if I did `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_temp_val);` (after correcting the cases on that variable to match each other, which also didn't match, above).  BUT, if I do `SELECT last_number INTO l_temp_val FROM user_sequences WHERE squence_name = 'MY_SEQ';` and output `l_temp_val` again, it equals `2`, not an increment of the last ID in my table.  You need `START WITH`instead of the first `increment by`.  Changed it in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is how sequence is supposed to be used.

```
22:05:18 HR@vm_xe> create table test_seq_tab(a number, b number);                                            

Table created.                                                                                               

Elapsed: 00:00:00.85                                                                                         
22:05:43 HR@vm_xe> create sequence test_seq start with 1 increment by 1;                                     

Sequence created.                                                                                            

Elapsed: 00:00:00.12                                                                                         
22:06:33 HR@vm_xe> insert into test_seq_tab select test_seq.nextval, rownum from dual connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.                                                                                             

Elapsed: 00:00:00.11                                                                                         
22:06:40 HR@vm_xe> select * from test_seq_tab;                                                               

         A          B                                                                                        
---------- ----------                                                                                        
         1          1                                                                                        
         2          2                                                                                        
         3          3                                                                                        
         4          4                                                                                        
         5          5                                                                                        
         6          6                                                                                        
         7          7                                                                                        
         8          8                                                                                        
         9          9                                                                                        
        10         10                                                                                        

10 rows selected.                                                                                            

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10                                                                                         
22:06:50 HR@vm_xe> select test_seq.currval from dual;                                                        

   CURRVAL                                                                                                   
----------                                                                                                   
        10                                                                                                   

1 row selected.                                                                                              

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01                                                                                         
22:07:04 HR@vm_xe>
```

No `select max ...` is needed. Are you doing it this way?

Comment: this is where you lose me.  I am using powerbuilder and I want to take the info I have and pass it into the table with an insert.  I want each new INSERT to have the ID incremented by 1, and I was told I needed to use a sequence, but this seems to confuse me.  I figured I could assign the max(id) to the current value, then increment by 1?

Comment: `sequence.nextval` automatically increments your id either by 1, or by `increment by` value, depending on how you've created it

Comment: so, unless you care about some specific ids (say you need this row have exactly id = 100), all you need to do is specify `your_sequence_name.nextval` in your insert statement

Comment: another possible issue is when you have pre-filled table having data with ids ranging from, say, 1 to 100, and you already have sequence with .currval = 50. then you would probably have to adjust it to 100 - see Rajesh's answer

Comment: This answer isn't relevant if say, you're trying to move a table to another database with existing data, but then have to re-assign the sequence to start at the last ID again.  This is the beginning point, like how it might've been previously set up in the old table, so I won't downvote, but it's not the endpoint (new table setup) and acts like there's no use-case for the OP's question.  You aren't going to start all over at 1 in the new table if you have pre-existing values.